# Definition of instantaneous frequency in Wikipedia

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, signal-processing

[Wikipedia defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantaneous_phase#Instantaneous_frequency) the instantaneous frequency of a function $s(t)$ by derivative of $\frac{1}{2\pi}\arg(s(t)+i\widehat{s}(t))$ where $\widehat{s}$ is the Fourier transform of $s$ and $i$ is imaginary one.

Then [in another page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp#Definitions) defines the instantaneous frequency of a function $\sin (s(t))$ by derivative of $\frac{1}{2\pi}s(t)$.

Are these two definitions the same (or compatible)?

Comment: $\hat{s}(t)$ should be the Hilbert Transform, not the Fourier Transform.  In that case, yes they are compatible and represent $\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ of the function.  Although the first $s(t)$ refers to the real function and the second $s(t) = \phi(t)$.